# If a topological space X admits a one-point compactification , then X must be locally compact and Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that if a topological space X admits a one-point compactification , then X must be locally compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Answer (score 2):

If a one-point compactification of $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space $Y$ such that there is a point $p\in Y$ such that $Y\setminus\{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$, then the proof is easy:

A subspace of a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff and an open subspace of a compact Hausdorff space is locally compact.

Comment: @SantanaAfton yes, I edited the typo.